# Keep md-sidenav open by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have created a `md-sidenav`. I want to keep the `sidenav` open by default, but i still want the `sidenav` to be displayed overlaying the page and I want to be able to close the `sidenav`- therefore I don't want to use the `md-is-locked-open` expression. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

html Code:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button hamburger" aria-label="More" ng-click="openLeftMenu()" style="height: auto;">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="images/menu.svg"></md-icon>

        </md-button>

<md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2 menuside" md-component-id="left"> 

    <div class="navheader" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">

        <!--show location-->
        <md-button ui-sref="map" ng-click="openLeftMenu()" md-ink-ripple="false" class="yourlocation" layout="row" layout-align="start center" aria-label="Current-location">
            <p class="locationtext">{{currentLocation}}</p>
        </md-button>


        <!--close menu-->
        <button class="hambugerclose" ng-click="openLeftMenu()">
            <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>

    </div>

    <!--MOBILE MENU GRID-->
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="jumbowrapper2" layout-wrap>
        <div ng-repeat="navitem in navitems" class="navitemwrap" flex="33">
            <md-button md-ink-ripple="false" layout="column" layout-align="center center" ui-sref="{{navitem.path}}" href="{{navitem.link}}" ng-click="openLeftMenu()" class="itembutton">
                <div class="iconoutline" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                    <md-icon class="itemicon" md-svg-src="{{navitem.icon}}"></md-icon>
                </div>
                <p class="itemtext2" translate>{{navitem.title}}</p>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </div>

</md-sidenav>
```

Js Code:

```
$scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
$mdSidenav('left').toggle();
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I Used md-is-open as below code, it is working fine.

```
<md-sidenav md-is-open="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

`md-is-locked-open` is just set to equal a logical value. I would use it and have a property on my controller named something like KeepSideBarOpen and have a button that sets the value of this property to false when clicked. (And I'd probably use a custom controller for the side nav).

```
function sideNavController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.closeSideNav = closeSideNav;
    vm.sideNavOpen = true;

    function closeSideNav() {
         vm.sideNavOpen = false
    }

}
```

```html
<md-side-nav md-is-locked-open="ctrl.sideNavOpen">...</md-side-nav>
```

Then just put a button within your side nav (or elsewhere) that calls closeSideNav

Answer (score 0):

By "default" I assume you mean be open on initial page load. I accomplished this by making a sidenav toggle function just like yours ...

```
$scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
  $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
};
```

And then I call this function when the document is ready ...

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.openLeftMenu()
});
```

This will allow the sidenav to still overlay the page nicely.